# First data file in Chronicle Queue is always touched

Tags: chronicle-queue

We're wondering why ChronicleQueue always seems to touch the first data file. Is there a reason for it?

The other filer don't seem to be affected, even if data is read from them. Are we doing something wrong?

Currently we're using version 5.19.2.

```
[root@node-000341 dataLog]# ls -al
total 16520
drwxrwxr-x. 2 tn tn     4096 Jan 13 15:17 .
drwxrwxr-x. 7 tn tn       94 Apr 14  2020 ..
-rw-r--r--. 1 tn tn 83886080 Jan 12 11:46 20200424.cq4
-rw-r--r--. 1 tn tn 83886080 May  5  2020 20200427.cq4
-rw-r--r--. 1 tn tn   131782 May 12  2020 20200505.cq4
-rw-r--r--. 1 tn tn   131574 May 13  2020 20200512.cq4
.....
-rw-r--r--. 1 tn tn   389465 Dec 16 09:26 20201210.cq4
-rw-r--r--. 1 tn tn   184090 Jan 12 12:07 20201216.cq4
-rw-r--r--. 1 tn tn   361994 Jan 13 15:17 20210112.cq4
-rw-r--r--. 1 tn tn 83886080 Jan 13 15:22 20210113.cq4
-rw-r--r--. 1 tn tn    65536 Jan 13 15:21 metadata.cq4t
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a tailer, by default it goes toStart(), which is the first file, which is what causes the first file to be touched (note that `ls` shows access time, not modification time).

BTW unless you really need that access time for any reason, we suggest using `noatime` mount option to speed up file access.

Comment: Thanks. But the man page of ls says it is the modification time, not the access time.

Comment: I vaguely remember that doesn't hold for ext4 but can't find a proof easily. In any case, it might be updating modification time because we open file read/write when we mmap file, even if we only read stuff.